# How can I use parameter to replace a mongodb connection string in a lambda function in AWS SAM?

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, sam

In my amplify lambda backend project, template.yaml file mentioned connection string for mongodb connection for all lambda functions respectively like below example.

```yaml
Resources:
  authenticateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/member/authenticateMember.authenticateMemberHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: A simple example includes a HTTP post method to add one item to a DynamoDB table.
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CONNECTION_STRING: mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0.xx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /member/authenticate
            Method: POST
```

I want to replace the above one with the other one like below using paramater. I need your assist to correct the below snippet of template.yaml?

```yaml
Parameters:
  ConnectionString:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Description: Enter SSM key for the mongodsb connection string, including user name and password

Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 20
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'content-type'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      AllowCredentials: "'*'"

Resources:
  authenticateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/member/authenticateMember.authenticateMemberHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: A simple example includes a HTTP post method to add one item to a DynamoDB table.
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CONNECTION_STRING: !Ref ConnectionString
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /member/authenticate
            Method: POST
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what was the outcome of your current yaml file?

Comment: 500 internal server error. before changing template.yaml, it connected mongo and responses worked properly.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't catch you exactly. why do you need to change the old yaml that works well now? are you trying to run the app on local?

Comment: I need more detail to understand your situation.

Comment: Sorry for confusing.
I tried to run the amplify project on my local using SAM cli.
There are many lambda functions and each one has mongodb connection string inside in template.yaml.
So I am going to manipulate this with a parameter. But with the new template.yaml, after run the app on local, postman shows 500 error.
That is to say, couldn't connect database.

Comment: gotcha, you can simply add Default option in ConnectionString of Parameter. let me update you in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
Parameters:
  ConnectionString:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Description: Enter SSM key for the mongodsb connection string, including user name and password
    Default: mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0.xx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Please try with this configuration. You can replace the temp string of "Default" with your correct connection string.

And double check for all resources whether they have "CONNECTION_STRING: !Ref ConnectionString" inside.

Hope this answer help you.